# Value of class variable is always null when accessed

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am making an api call in a function and updating the value of a class variable (name) in that function. Now, when I check the value of that variable, its fine. But when I try to access it anywhere else in the same class, it returns me nothing. I have tried all possible solutions. Here is the code.

```
private void PopulateName()
        {
            try
            {
                string data1 = WebOp.baseUrl1 + "" + Const.action + "=" + Const.productByCategory + "" +
                 "&" + Const.category_id + "=" + category_id;


                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                {

                    RunOnUiThread(() => { progressDialog.Show(); });

                    WebOp webOp = new WebOp();
                    String str = webOp.doPost1(data1, this);

                    JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(str);


                    string status = jobj[Const.status].ToString();

                    if (status.Equals(Const.success))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string data = jobj[Const.data].ToString();
                            myDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductDto>>(data)[0];
                            name = myDto.thecategory_name;
                            Console.WriteLine("Check value:" + name); //returns the value fine
                            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                            {

                                progressDialog.Dismiss();
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e + "");
                            RunOnUiThread(() => { progressDialog.Dismiss(); });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            progressDialog.Dismiss();
                        });
                    }


                }).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1 + "");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Check again:" + name); //returns nothing
        }
```

Comment: You start a Task to update 'name' but don't await it, so the code that writes out 'name' will almost always be executed before the task has even started execution (and before name has received its value).

Comment: @JohanDonne I have even tried ConfigureAwait(true) but no luck.

Comment: The moment I get out of system threading task, name is empty. I have added two console writeline statements with comments. Please check it out.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ works fine there too.

Comment: 'ConfigureAwait' does not make your code wait for the Task to finish...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Task to run in the background and print the value of 'name' only after the Task has finished, your best choice is to use 'Async..Await'.
To do this you make your method async and explicitly await the Task:

```
    // declare the method as Async using a return type of 'Task'
    private async Task PopulateName()
    {
        try
        {
            string data1 = WebOp.baseUrl1 + "" + Const.action + "=" + Const.productByCategory + "" +
             "&" + Const.category_id + "=" + category_id;

            // explicitly await the Task...
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
            {

                RunOnUiThread(() => { progressDialog.Show(); });

                WebOp webOp = new WebOp();
                String str = webOp.doPost1(data1, this);

                JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(str);


                string status = jobj[Const.status].ToString();

                if (status.Equals(Const.success))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string data = jobj[Const.data].ToString();
                        myDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductDto>>(data)[0];
                        name = myDto.thecategory_name;
                        Console.WriteLine("Check value:" + name); //returns the value fine
                        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {

                            progressDialog.Dismiss();
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e + "");
                        RunOnUiThread(() => { progressDialog.Dismiss(); });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        progressDialog.Dismiss();
                    });
                }


            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e1 + "");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Check again:" + name); //returns nothing
    }
```

Comment: Will the compiler execute next lines or will it wait for this task to be finished and then proceed?

Comment: It will start the task and wit for it to finish before proceeding to the 'Console.WriteLine' statement. Just try it...